# Android: Querying contacts saved on the device by other users

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, multi-user

In multi-user android device, How to query contacts saved by another user from currently active user.

I want to query contacts database from **System UI** Process. Since **System UI** runs in owner mode, it can't access the contacts of another user even if the owner is not an active user. Is there any way to achieve this?

I searched thoroughly about this on the net but could not find any such concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app data is sandboxed by user/profile, so what you want is not possible